# Instantiate content in resusable UIViewController

Tags: swift

I'm creating a set of tutorial screens to introduce my App.

Previously I've had three different viewcontrollers and then loaded them into my UIPageViewController. However this is inefficient since they use the same colors and format.

That format (for reference) is here:

[image]

So I want to create three instances of this view controller and put them into an array for my UIPageViewController. I instantiate with:

```
UIStoryboard(name : "Main" , bundle : nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "test")
```

So previously I've done this, and then created a func in the view controller to set the text

```
let vc = UIStoryboard(name : "Main" , bundle : nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "test")
vc.setMainText(text: "label Text")
```

I want to set my view up using the storyboard so  setting up the view controller entirely programmatically is out of the question.

I'm thinking I should use an initializer for the view - So how can I use an initializer if I'm using instantiateViewController:withIdentifier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So how can I use an initializer if I'm using `instantiateViewController:withIdentifier`

You can't. The view controller arrives already initialized.

- You could have three different instances *of the same view controller class* in your storyboard, each designed in its own way. That way, each identifier would give you an instance already themed as you want it.
- Alternatively, you could arm your view controller class with instance properties that you can set so as to customize the theme, and set those properties on each instance after you get it from the storyboard.